# How to extract numbers with repeating digits within a range

Tags: python-3.x, digits

I need to identify the count of numbers with non-repeating digits in the range of two numbers.
Suppose n1=11 and n2=15.

There is the number 11, which has repeated digits, but 12, 13, 14 and 15 have no repeated digits. So, the output is 4.

Wrote this code:

```
n1=int(input())
n2=int(input())

count=0

for i in range(n1,n2+1):
    lst=[]
    x=i
    while (n1>0):
        a=x%10
        lst.append(a)
        x=x//10
    for j in range(0,len(lst)-1):
      for k in range(j+1,len(lst)):
        if (lst[j]==lst[k]):
            break
        else:
            count=count+1
print (count)
```

While running the code and after inputting the two numbers, it does not run the code but still accepts input. What did I miss?

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code doesn't run is because it gets stuck in your `while` loop, it can never exit that condition, since `n1 > 0` will never have a chance to be evaluated as `False`, unless the input itself is `<= 0`.

Anyway, your approach is over complicated, not quite readable and not exactly pythonic. Here's a simpler, and more readable approach:

```py
from collections import Counter

n1 = int(input())
n2 = int(input())

count = 0

for num in range(n1, n2+1):
    num = str(num)
    digit_count = Counter(num)
    has_repeating_digits = any((True for count in digit_count.values() if count > 1))

    if not has_repeating_digits:
        count += 1

print(count)
```

When writing code, in general you should try to avoid nesting too much stuff (in your original example you have 4 nested loops, that's readability and debugging nightmare), and try using self-describing variable names (so a, x, j, k, b... are kind of a no-go).

If in a IPython session you run `import this` you can also read the "Zen of Python", which kind of sums up the concept of writing proper pythonic code.

Comment: Yea thanks for the solution. I tried another simplified method by using set() as I don't have to find which is repeating.

 x=str(n1);
    if len(set(x))==len(x):
        count=count+1
But count just prints the total numbers between the range. I have no idea why

Comment: Your 2nd solution works too and it's even less verbose than mine. If count prints the total numbers and not just what you needed, it's probably a logical error in the order of instructions that you wrote. Try double checking your code line by line. Btw if you liked the answer and thought it was appropriate, don't forget to upvote it and mark it as a solution.